# How to show spinner when post back occur on anchor tag click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have spinner in my website. I have bind spinner to anchor on click and check it contains href attribute. It's working fine, I have given some validation on anchor click if its passes validation then post back will occur. My problem is when it not pass the validation then also spinner is showing. How to stop it if its not pass the validation.

Here is my code:

My jQuery:

```
    var myVar,
        ShowProgress = function () {
            myVar = setTimeout(function () {
                var modal = $('<div />');
                modal.addClass("modal");
                $('body').append(modal);
                var loading = $(".loading");
                loading.show();
                var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
                var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
                loading.css({
                    top: top,
                    left: left
                });
            }, 200);
        };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(this.getElementById('form1')).submit(ShowProgress);
        $('a').click(function (evt) {
            var hrf = $(this).attr('href');
            if (hrf != "#" && hrf != "") {
                ShowProgress();
                evt.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

My HTML

```
    function Validate {
        if (!CheckDDL('<%= ddlDepartment.ClientID %>', 'Alert - pls select a department!!!')) {               
            return false;
        }
        if (!CheckDDL('<%= ddlDesignation.ClientID %>', 'Alert - pls select a designation!!!')) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!CheckDDL('<%= ddlType.ClientID %>', 'Alert - pls select type!!!')) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

MY HTML...

```
 <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 103px;">Departmnet : <span class="errorStar">*</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartment" runat="server" Width="330px"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Designation : <span class="errorStar">*</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDesignation" runat="server" Width="330px"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Type : <span class="errorStar">*</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlType" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="">[ -- SELECT TYPE -- ]</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Goal">Goal</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Competencies">Competencies</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Perspective : <span class="errorStar">*</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPerspective" runat="server" Width="330px"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" Width="80px" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" OnClientClick="return Validate();" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnBack1" runat="server" OnClick="btnBack1_Click" Text="Back" Width="80px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: First of all, `ready` function takes a function as an argument, not a selector

Comment: @f00bar then what to do that my problem is get solved.

Comment: I've edited your code, try it then tell us what's still wrong

Comment: @f00bar i think you have not got my problem. problem is that, spiner is working fine, but i want to show its only when post back occur after anchor tag click.

Comment: I did not intend to solve your problem, otherwise I would have post a solution `:)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, `clearTimeout(myVar)` should solve your problem.

**Also:** Please read the [documentation on jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/).

**UPDATE:**

Here is the updated version of your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var progressTimer,
        showProgress = function() {
            progressTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                var modal = $('<div />');
                modal.addClass("modal");
                $('body').append(modal);
                var loading = $(".loading");
                loading.show();
                var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
                var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
                loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
            }, 200);
        },
        hideProgess = function() {
            clearTimeout(progressTimer);
        };

    $('a').click(function () {
        var hrf = $(this).attr('href');
        if (hrf != "#" && hrf != "") {
            showProgress();
        } else {
            hideProgess();
        }
    });

    $("#form1").submit(function (event) {
        showProgress();
    });
});
```

Comment: i have tried it but its note working, because javascript validation get called first then spiner is coming.

Comment: @Raghubar I've just updated your code. Check it out.